# My XML content contains &amp;#xd; why is XSLT 1.0 not converting this into line breaks?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xslt-1.0, line-breaks, multiline

I have multi line text present in an SQL column, and I am fetching the data from an SQL query. My query is inserting at the end of each line.

**Query:**

```sql
Declare @vcFooterText  Varchar(max)
Select @vcFooterText = (Select replace(replace(AppConfigValue,CHAR(13),'&#xd;'),CHAR(10),'&#xd;') From COM.Config_Application With (NoLock) Where AppConfigId = 'PackingNoteFooterText')
Select @vcFooterText
```

**Query Result:**

```
Line 1&#xd;Line 2 &#xd;Line 3
```

Then XML is used which is showing the data:

```sql
Select tbl.OrderNumber,  Cast(
    (
        '<Documents><Document><PackingNote>' +
        Cast((
            Select
            CustomerName CustomerName,
            Convert(Varchar(10), OrderCreatedOn, 103) + ' ' + Convert(Varchar(5), OrderCreatedOn, 114) As OrderDate,
            CustomerNumber CustomerNumber,
            OrderNumber OrderNumber,
            BatchNumber BatchNumber,
            ChannelOrderNumber ChannelOrderNumber,
            OrderChannel OrderChannel,
            Case
                When DM.Category = 1501 ANd DM.SubCategory <> 1604 Then 'Click and Collect'
                When DM.Category = 1502 Then 'Home Delivery'

            End 'OrderType',
            @vCompanyName as CompanyName,
            @vCompanyEmail as CompanyEmail,
            @vCompanyURL as CompanyURL,
            @vCollectionPointValue as CollectionPointValue,
            Case
                when @vCheckCollectionPoint = 'True' Then 'Collection Point'
            END 'CollectionPoint',
            Case
                When DM.Category = 1501 ANd DM.SubCategory <> 1604 Then 'Collect'
                When DM.Category = 1502 Then 'Despatch'
                When DM.Category = 1501 And DM.SubCategory = 1604 Then (Select AppConfigValue from Catalogue.COM.Config_Application
                                                                        Where AppConfigId='SameDayShippingLabel')
            End 'DeliveryMethod',
            (Case When DM.Category = 1502 Then 1 Else 0 End) As 'IsHomeDelivery',
            (CASE
                WHEN DM.Category = 1502
                THEN
                CAST(
                    (
                       SELECT
                       ISNULL(OA.Name, CustomerName) CustomerName,
                       OA.AddressLines AddressLines,
                       OA.City City,
                       OA.PostalCode PostalCode,
                       OA.Country Country
                       FROM COM.Order_Address OA WITH (NoLock)
                       INNER JOIN COM.DeliveryMethod DM WITH (NoLock) ON DM.pkDeliveryMethodId = tbl.DeliveryMethodId
                       AND (DM.Category = 1502
                       OR DM.SubCategory = 1604) --HomeDelivery
                       AND OA.OrderId = tbl.OrderId
                       AND OA.AddressType = 'SHIP'
                       FOR
                       XML PATH('')
                       ) AS    XML
                       )
                ELSE
                CAST(
                    (
                       SELECT
                       ISNULL(B.Name, CustomerName) CustomerName,
                       A.Street AddressLines,
                       A.City City,
                       A.PostalCode PostalCode,
                       A.County Country
                       FROM Catalogue..Branch B WITH (NoLock)
                       INNER JOIN Catalogue.COM.[Order] O WITH (NoLock) ON O.CollectStoreId = B.pkBranchID
                       INNER JOIN Catalogue..[Address] A WITH (NoLock) ON A.fkBranchID = O.CollectStoreId
                       INNER JOIN COM.DeliveryMethod DM WITH (NoLock) ON DM.pkDeliveryMethodId = tbl.DeliveryMethodId
                       AND (DM.Category = 1501
                       OR DM.SubCategory <> 1604) --CC
                       AND O.pkOrderId = tbl.OrderId
                       FOR
                       XML PATH('')
                       ) AS    XML
                       )
                       END  )
                       AS 'DeliveryAddress'


            From COM.DeliveryMethod DM With (NoLock) Where DM.pkDeliveryMethodId = tbl.DeliveryMethodId
            For Xml Path('Header'), Type
        ) As NVarchar(Max)) +
        Cast((
            Select  SKU    As 'Line/SKU',
                    Quantity As 'Line/Quantity',
                    ProductName As 'Line/ProductName',
                    Barcode As 'Line/Barcode',
                    Price As 'Line/Price'
            From @tblPrintOrderLines Where OrderNumber = tbl.OrderNumber
        For Xml Path('Lines'), Type
        ) As Varchar(Max)) +
        Cast((
            Select SUM(Quantity),
            OrderNotes OrderNotes,
            @vcFooterText As Text
            From @tblPrintOrderLines Where OrderNumber = tbl.OrderNumber
            For Xml Path('TotalItems'), Type
        ) As Varchar(Max)) +
        '</PackingNote></Document></Documents>'
        )
 As XML) As 'XML',
 @xmlTemplate As XSLT
From @tblOrderData tbl
```

**XML content:**

This is the XML content that is produced:

```xml
<Documents>
    <Document>
        <PackingNote>
            <Header>
                <CustomerName>laura haines</CustomerName>
                <OrderDate>15/09/2017 20:38</OrderDate>
                <CustomerNumber>000003</CustomerNumber>
                <OrderNumber>000024</OrderNumber>
                <BatchNumber>1 of 1</BatchNumber>
                <OrderType>Click and Collect</OrderType>
                <CompanyName>The Retail Suite</CompanyName>
                <CompanyURL />
                <DeliveryMethod>Collect</DeliveryMethod>
                <IsHomeDelivery>0</IsHomeDelivery>
                <DeliveryAddress>
                    <CustomerName>ACC</CustomerName>
                    <AddressLines>London</AddressLines>
                    <City>London</City>
                </DeliveryAddress>
            </Header>
            <Lines>
                <Line>
                    <SKU>000044</SKU>
                    <Quantity>9</Quantity>
                    <ProductName>Partial Cancel 001</ProductName>
                    <Price>135.00</Price>
                </Line>
            </Lines>
            <TotalItems>9<Text>Line 1&amp;#xD;Line 2 &amp;#xD;Line 3</Text></TotalItems>
        </PackingNote>
    </Document>
</Documents>
```

How I can get line breaks using XSL 1.0?

**XSLT 1.0:**

```xml
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="1mm" padding-left="0.5cm">
        <fo:block font-size="10pt" text-align="left">
            <xsl:value-of select="text" />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

**Current output:**

```
Line 1&#xd;Line 2 &#xd;Line 3
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Comment: How are you producing the XML? The `&` is properly escaped as `&amp;`, preserving the actual text (and not interpreting it as an entity). To a first approximation, you can have actual XML in SQL by `declare @vcFooterText XML`, but this is no guarantee of success -- it depends on what happens with the value afterwards.

Comment: This is my xml <Documents>
  <Document>
    <PackingNote>
      <Header>
        <CustomerName>laura haines</CustomerName>
       
      </Header>
      <Lines>
        <Line>
          <SKU>000044</SKU>
          <Quantity>9</Quantity>
          <ProductName>Partial Cancel 001</ProductName>
          <Price>135.00</Price>
        </Line>
      </Lines>
      <TotalItems>9<Text>Line 1&amp;#xD;Line 2 &amp;#xD;Line 3</Text></TotalItems>
    </PackingNote>
  </Document>
</Documents>

Comment: My question is not what your XML *is*, but how you get `@vcFooterText` as XML into your XSLT processor. The XML you've shown is already wrong by the time it's processed, because something (?) is escaping the text before it gets there. Declaring `@vcFooterText` as `XML` would at least produce an entity reference in the XML itself.

Comment: This has nothing to do with XSLT. Your second query double-encodes the XML stored in `@vcFooterText`. Make it an XML too with a bogus root node, or move the query that generates `@vcFooterText` inside the main query and make sure it also uses `, Type` like the other XML subqueries there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XSLT 1.0, replace this line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text" />
```

with:

```
<xsl:call-template name="replace">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

and add this to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-string" select="'&amp;#xD;'"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace-string" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $search-string)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $search-string)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replace-string"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $search-string)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Note**: XML is case-sensitive, and in your XML the element is named `Text` not `text`. So it should really be:

```
<xsl:call-template name="replace">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Text"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: It's much better to generate non-double-encoded XML to begin with rather than undo the double encoding afterwards.

Comment: @GSerg I agree, but this question is tagged `xslt`, so an XSLT answer is relevant and may be useful to the OP.  Feel free to post another answer relating to one of the other tags.

Answer (score -2):

> How I can get line breaks using XSL 1.0?

In your query, you can replace the `CHAR` with `&#xa;` OR `&#10;` instead of `&#xd;`

**OR**

In **XSLT 1.0**, you can do the same as below:

```
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="1mm" padding-left="0.5cm">
    <fo:block font-size="10pt" text-align="left">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(text,'&amp;#xd;','&#xa;')" />
    </fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

XSLT would convert `&#xa;` OR `&#10;` in line breaks. Refer to the **updated** transformation [here](http://xsltransform.net/nbiCsZ3/1).

**To correct**:

In XSLT 1.0, it's needed to write a recursive template to replace a string or `xmlns:str="xalan://org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils"` can be used, which provides the `replace()' method.

Comment: Hi it is giving error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 352
Incorrect syntax near '#xd'.

Comment: You cannot use `replace()` in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: My bad. In XSLT 1.0, `xmlns:str="xalan://org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils"` is used to replace strings. Will update the answer accordingly

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check if it's working at your end.

Comment: I am afraid you completely misunderstand how the `translate()` function works. See an example of what your expression does here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38YR

Comment: @michael.hor257k : I know that `translate` function returns the first argument string with occurrences of characters in the second argument string replaced by the character at the corresponding position in the third argument string. But for the given XML, (just to solve the problem) I only verified it with **Saxon 9.5.1.6 HE** and not with **MSXML 6**